# two dryers on the same circuit

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel, dryer, wire, 240v

I would like to have two dryers in my laundry room. Can I run both off of the same circuit? Can the outlets be run in series? What upgrades do I need to make for this to work. I have room for another breaker in my box, which is in the same room. I am doing extensive work, including removing drywall, in the laundry room and now would be the time to make changes.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you want to run both dryers at the same time?   If *not*, can you explain why you would want two?

Answer (score 4):

Ok here's the math. NEC Article 220 requires electricians to provide 5000W/240V circuit for each dwelling dryer. Most nameplates will give you a total demand of 4500W. So 4500+4500= (9000W/240V)= 37.5A. 37.5A won't work on a 30A breaker and it exceeds the rating of the #10 conductor that is usually feeding the circuit. Also you cannot wire appliances in series, that would give you 120V drop across both dryers so it would not work. You would have to run them in parallel.

The normal method is to run a separate circuit for each dryer, which is what I would recommend. In other words don't try to reinvent the wheel. Just follow proven methods.

Answer (score 1):

If you need it to work simply and reliably, have both dryers work, and definitely pass inspection -- your best (and probably only real) bet is running another dedicated "30A" circuit to the second dryer.  Dryers are typically 5500W, which is just shy of the 5760 watt maximum for a 30A circuit (240V x 30A x 0.8 for the continuous derate).

The only way to share a 30A circuit is using a DPDT switch so only one dryer could possibly be on at once.  (Of course this would defeat the purpose of having two dryers.)  The practical way to do that with readily available hardware is use a panel intended for a mains/generator interlock.  Backfeed it, so one dryer is connected to "generator" and the other to "mains".

However since your panel is so close and you have spare spaces, you might as well run the second cable and have no restrictions.

Now, if you are in fact out of space in the panel, you might as well install a subpanel.  Since *it is likely* both dryers would be on at the same time, you would need to provision 60A just for the two dryers - and more if you want to power anything else there.  (and this is a good way to get some spare panel capacity, because being down to one space really sucks.)  Like I say, don't scrimp on space, I would go at least 24 space, it'll come in handy later.